# unable to read data of Blockchain

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js

[output page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVEF6.png)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import ABI from "./ABIS/convertAbi.json";

function Temp() {
const [value, setvalue] = useState(null);
const [input, setInput] = useState(null);
const feather = async () => {
console.log("working");
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  AddressofCOntract,
  ABI,
  signer
);
const dollarValue = await contract.getDollartoEth(input);
console.log(dollarValue);
setvalue(dollarValue);
};
useEffect(() => {
feather();
 }, []);

return (
<div>
  <input
    value={input}
    type="number"
    onInput={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
  />
  <h1> Dollar : {value}</h1>
  <p>Ether : {input}</p>
  <button onClick={feather}>Convert</button>
</div>
);
}

export default Temp;
```

I am not able to read data of the blockchain [output screenshot], i can see that it is able to read the function after the button click but unfortunately it is not able to read the data of the goerli testnet.

Comment: AddressofCOntract
Where did you define address value?

Comment: i entered the address under contract variable, didn't share the address here